# How to close accordion on second click? (css & JS only)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple accordion that closes the current panel when clicking a new one. This works just like I want it to.

However, I'd like to be able to also close the current open panel by clicking it again. What would I need to add to the code to do that?

No jQuery please :)

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    for(var it of elems) {
      it.classList.remove("expanded");
      it.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
    }

    this.classList.toggle("expanded");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });

}
```

```css
.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
}

.expanded:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion"></button>
<div class="panel">
 Text 1
</div>

<button class="accordion"></button>
<div class="panel">
 Text 2
</div>

<button class="accordion"></button>
<div class="panel">
 Text 3
</div>

<button class="accordion"></button>
<div class="panel">
 Text 4
</div>
```

Comment: you can use a click counter variable inside the click function, if the click is odd, the toggle takes place, if the click is even you remove the expanded class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try This :

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;      
        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var setClasses = !this.classList.contains('expanded');
        for(var it of elems) {
            console.log(it);
          it.classList.remove("expanded");
          it.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
        }       
        if (setClasses) {
            this.classList.toggle("expanded");
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }       
        });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very short implementation, reducing the amount of code will give you a better oversight of your code.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

function toggle (el) {

  let nextElement = el.nextElementSibling;
  
  nextElement.className === 'panel' ? nextElement.className = '' : nextElement.className = 'panel';

}
```

```css
.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
}

.expanded:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle(this)" class="accordion"></button>
<div class="panel">
 Text 1
</div>

<button onclick="toggle(this)" class="accordion"></button>
<div class="panel">
 Text 2
</div>

<button onclick="toggle(this)" class="accordion"></button>
<div class="panel">
 Text 3
</div>

<button onclick="toggle(this)" class="accordion"></button>
<div class="panel">
 Text 4
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! However, the toggle function requires jQuery right? I'd like to do this with vanilla JS and CSS only.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I didn't look at the HTML code. I see you're not using jQuery toggle :)